# LINQ query with calculated value using let clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using ASP.NET Core version 1.1 with Entity Framework.

I have a database with a table for Engines and one for Tests run on the engines. I am trying to get the last test result and display it along with each engine record. I would also like to perform a calculation with the test result.

I would like to do something like the following in my controller and display the result in a view:

```
var engines = from engine in _context.Engine
              orderby engine.SerialNumber
              let lastTest =
                (from t in _context.Test
                 where t.EngineId == engine.EngineId
                 orderby t.TestDate descending
                 select t.TestValue)
                .FirstOrDefault()
              select new EngineVM
              {
                  EngineId = engine.EngineId,
                  Make = engine.Make,
                  Model = engine.Model,
                  SerialNumber = engine.SerialNumber,
                  Status = CalculateEngineStatus(engine.EngineId, engine.AllowedAmount, lastTest)
              };
```

I get the following error:

**SqlException**: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I have tried different ways to write the query but I haven't been successful. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is clearly wrong approach, you must use navigation properties and avoid any EXISTS, JOIN etc.Have you defined foreign key relation in your model?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's failing with a *SqlException*, but it looks like an issue with the EF core SQL Translator (I'm not having that problem in EF 6)

Nevertheless, the following *equivalent* query works (via outer join)

```
var lastTestQuery = from test in _context.Test
                    group test by test.EngineId into engineTests
                    select (from t in engineTests orderby t.TestDate descending select t).FirstOrDefault();

var engines = from engine in _context.Engine
            orderby engine.SerialNumber
            join lastTest in lastTestQuery on engine.EngineId equals lastTest.EngineId into lastEngineTest
            let lastEngineTestValue = (from t in lastEngineTest select t.TestValue).FirstOrDefault()
            select new EngineVM
            {
                EngineId = engine.EngineId,
                Make = engine.Make,
                Model = engine.Model,
                SerialNumber = engine.SerialNumber,
                Status = CalculateEngineStatus(engine.EngineId, engine.AllowedAmount, lastEngineTestValue)
            };
```

**Note:** After a little research, using SQL Server Profiler, it looks like EF Core will translate this into two `SELECT` statements for *all engines and all tests*. The SQL Translator for EF 6 executes a single query, but that's *NOT the case for EF Core* which solves the problem in memory. You should probably redesign this piece of code and come up with something that EF Core finds easier to digest

Answer (score 0):

You have already written the query. You can't select from after firstOrDefault since it doesn't return a collection. Do as follows:

```
var engines = from engine in _context.Engine
orderby engine.SerialNumber
let lastTest =
(from t in _context.Test
 where t.EngineId == engine.EngineId
 orderby t.TestDate descending
select t.TestValue)
.FirstOrDefault();


 if(engines != null)
{
 // do your calculation here
}
```

Comment: In visual studio I get a syntax error "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"